# How to calculate percentage for battery level indicator?

Tags: percentages

I'm doing a hobby project which i want to display battery voltage in a OLED display. I have a battery indicator with 30 pixels width.

i want to display when battery is 8.4V full 30 pixels width and when battery is 6v, 0 pixels.

currently I'm calculating how many pixels i want to display as below

indicatorWidth = (((voltage / 8.4) * 100) * 30) / 100;

When battery is at 6v this shows 21 pixels.

how do i fix this to show 0 width when at 6v and 30 width at 8.4v?

Regards

Comment: Is this a maths question or  a physics question(i don't know just asking)

Comment: Your indicatorWidth function is directly proportional to the voltage $v$, which means that when $v$ goes to 0, the width goes to 0. You instead want a function that's directly proportional to $v-6$ (think a little about why). Now, just modify your proportionality constant to give you a function that behaves the way you want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You subtract $6$ from $v$.  Now the range is only $2.4$, so your width would be $\frac {v-6}{2.4} \cdot 30$  The problem with this is that battery capacity is not linear in voltage, but it answers the question you asked.